# How can I send IQs to multiple recipients with Smack without sending them multiple times?

Tags: xmpp, smack

I'm using SmackAPI to transmit custom IQ Packets between two Java applications. The XMPP Server is a local OpenFire installation. In principle the sending and receiving of this packets works fine. But now i want to send to multiple recipients. For messages this can be done very easily by using the MultipleRecipientManager class. But I have no idea how to send custom IQs to multiple recipients without sending them multiple times. I tried to just use the MultipleRecipientManager like with normal messages, but this is not working.   Adding an extension (MultipleAddresses) to the custom IQ object does not work and hardcoding the addresses in the getChildElementXML method also does not work.

I always get an error from the xmpp server. It tells, that the service is unavailable. I think the problem is, that the server does not know my custom IQ, but how can I change this?

Extended Stanza Addressing is supported by my Openfire installation. But it seems like it is only working for normal messages.

I hope someone knows how to solve that.

Best regards 
Stefan

Comment: Sorry, totally OT, but... best Title i seen in a long while, although totally read out of context.

Answer (score 1):

> For messages this can be done very easily by using the
>   MultipleRecipientManager class. But I have no idea how to send custom
>   IQs to multiple recipients without sending them multiple times.

There is no way to transfer the approach used by MultipleRecipientManager to IQs. You have to send them multiple times.

Your question makes me wonder if you haven't a design flaw in your implementation. IQ stanzas of type 'get' or 'set' need to be acknowledged by the receiver. That is also the reason why XEP-33 was specified to only work with messages. In theory you could use the 'from' attribute to track that every receiver has ack'd an IQ with an certain ID. But I guess this isn't done because it adds to much complexity to the protocol for little gain.

Anyway, it appears that you don't care for for the IQ results, so why not use messages instead?

Comment: Ok, i didn't know that it is not possible to acknowledge Stanzas with XEP-33. I will think about using messages for data, where multicasts are needed, and using IQ stanzas when I need acknowledgments. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Nobody prevents you from acknowledging message stanzas (I assume you are talking about message stanzs). It's just that responses (success/error) are **required** by the spec for IQs.